# How to customize database unique constraint error message in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a Name with a UNI constraint, and when a user registers a duplicate name, it throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'John' for key 'UK_t622yodh32su1s2wseebkimwp'
```

In the JSF view page, the exception caught by the exception handler is displayed to the user:

```
Duplicate entry 'John' for key 'UK_t622yodh32su1s2wseebkimwp'
```

Code:

```
public void register (Student student) {
   ...

catch (Exception e) {
            String errorMessage = getRootErrorMessage(e);
            FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, errorMessage, "Registration unsuccessful");
            facesContext.addMessage(null, m);
        }
}

private String getRootErrorMessage(Exception e) {

        String errorMessage = "Registration failed.";
        if (e == null) {
            return errorMessage;
        }

        Throwable t = e;
        while (t != null) {
            errorMessage = t.getLocalizedMessage();
            t = t.getCause();
        }

        return errorMessage;
    }
```

Registration.xhtml:

```
<p>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:commandButton id="register"
                    action="#{registrationController.register(registrationView.student)}" value="Register"
                    styleClass="register" />
                <h:messages styleClass="messages" errorClass="invalid"
                    infoClass="valid" warnClass="warning" globalOnly="true" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p>
```

The problem here is that, it only displays the exception error code, as above. I would like to the error message something like:

```
The user name has been registered, Please use another one. Thanks.
```

This is more user friendly, compared to the SQL constraint violation error message. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure about what you exactly mean with "exception error code"?

In your code you are explicitly putting the Java Exception message in the FacesMessage. If you want something different to be displayed to the user, than you should write something different into the FacesMessage.

However, I would suggest to simply check if the user already exists before you try to persist it. You should cover most of the cases with such simple pre-check(s):

```
public void register (Student student) {
    if(service.exists(student)) {
        String message = "The user name has been registered, Please use another one. Thanks.";
        FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, 
                                         "Registration unsuccessful");
        facesContext.addMessage(null, m);
    } else {
        try {
            service.create(student);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String errorMessage = getRootErrorMessage(e);
            FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, errorMessage, 
                                              "Registration unsuccessful");
            facesContext.addMessage(null, m);
        }
    }
}
```

Beside that you are able to explicitly check for an integrity constraint violation in your SQLException, but you are not able to distinguish between different types of such integrity constraint violations that way.

```
public static boolean isConstraintViolation(SQLException e) {
    return e.getSQLState().startsWith("23");
}
```

You may also check, whether the error message contains the String `Duplicate entry`, but that is not very reliable.

I would prefer the first suggested attempt with the precheck. If the user already exists, add a proper FacesMassages to the FacesContext. It will cover most of the cases. And in the very unlikely event, when two users register the same username at the same time, display an "Unexpected error" to the user.

Comment: what do you mean by "cover most of the cases"? Some will be missing?

Comment: when to display "display an "Unexpected error" to the " in the try block?

Comment: "Cover most cases": Only when two users register with the same name at the "same" time you may run into the IntegrityException. i.e. only if the exists() method in the registration process of user A is called exactly between the calls of exists() and create() in the registration process of another user B. We are talking about milliseconds here, but it *may* happen. Thus you have to handle the SQLException anyway.

Comment: "when to display": Just in the catch block.

Answer (score -1):

I think there's something wrong in adding messages vs jsf lifecycle try creating a PhaseListener to add messages in the faces context, something like this:

```
public class FacesMessagesListener implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(final PhaseEvent event) {
           //add my messages to facesContext
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(final PhaseEvent event) {
           //add my messages to facesContext
    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
    }
}
```

Comment: The 'addMessage' in my Exception handling code did catch the root cause of the exception, "Duplicate entry 'John' for key 'UK_t622yodh32su1s2wseebkimwp'". I kind of want to override this message with my own wording of the message, but reflect the same problem.